# Python pandas; fill in data frame with pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a large python script, which makes two dataframes A and B, and at the end, I want to fill in dataframe A with the values of dataframe B, and keep the columns of dataframe A, but it is not going well.

Dataframe A is like this

```
A   B    C    D    
1   ab
2   bc
3   cd

Dataframe B:
A  BB  CC 
1  C   10
2  C   11 
3  D   12
```

My output must be:

new dataframe

```
A   B    C   D  
1   ab   10
2   bc   11
3   cd       12
```

But my output is

```
A   B    C   D  
1   ab   
2   bc   
3   cd
```

Why is it not filling in the values of dataframe B? 
My command is

```
dfnew = dfB.pivot_table(index='A', columns='BB', values='CC').reindex(index=dfA.index, columns=dfA.columns).fillna(dfA)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by `index` column of `df` for align data, [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) or [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':['ab','bc','cd'], 'C':[np.nan] * 3,'D':[np.nan] * 3})
print (dfA)
   A   B   C   D
0  1  ab NaN NaN
1  2  bc NaN NaN
2  3  cd NaN NaN

dfB = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'BB':['C','C','D'], 'CC':[10,11,12]})
print (dfB)
   A BB  CC
0  1  C  10
1  2  C  11
2  3  D  12

df = dfB.pivot_table(index='A', columns='BB', values='CC')
print (df)
BB     C     D
A             
1   10.0   NaN
2   11.0   NaN
3    NaN  12.0

dfA = dfA.set_index('A').fillna(df).reset_index()
#dfA = dfA.set_index('A').combine_first(df).reset_index() 
print (dfA)
   A   B     C     D
0  1  ab  10.0   NaN
1  2  bc  11.0   NaN
2  3  cd   NaN  12.0
```

Comment: In my real script, I do not have only columns C and D, but there are more than 2000 columns. I can not specify them with the "drop" command. How can I adjust the command for the >2000 columns?

Comment: I change solution, please check it.

Comment: with both options, I get the message `Keyerror: 'A'` at line `dfA = dfA.set_index('A').combine_first(df).reset_index()`. Do I have to add `df = df.set_index('A')` for both dataframes before I run the pivot_table or not?

Comment: After pivot_table get column define in `index='A'` as new index of `df`. Then need create in `dfA` same column to `index` (if not set before). I try edit answer.

Comment: Or maybe it can be written simpliest - if need fillna or combine_first in 2 dataframes, need same index (df has also A, so no need set_index, but for dfA is it necessary, because A is column) with some overlaping column names. Please check my solution with sample data.

Comment: I still have problems with the index. I got a new error `pandas.core.index.InvalidIndexError`

Comment: I think there has to be some problem with data. Is possible send me your real data solutuion to my email if data not confidental? If yes, try anonymize data. Because very hard to answer because your data - is necessary find difference between my answer and real data. Is it possible?